# Hilbert basis of $L^2([-1,1])$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Could you please specify hilbert basis of $L^2([-1,1])$? How will be the representation of a function f $\in L^2([-1,1])$ by means of its Fourier series? 
My solution: 
$E_k=1/\sqrt2 e^{kit\pi}, k\in Z$ 
$f=\sum_{k \in Z} c_kE_k$ 
$c_k=<f,E_k> =\int_{-1}^1 f(t) \overline{E_k(t)}dt$

Comment: Do you know what a Fourier series and an hilbert basis are ?

Comment: Yes, I know. I would like to check that my solution is correct or not?

Comment: "I would like to check my solution is correct or not" What is your solution?

Comment: I am editing now

Comment: Have you checked that the basis elements ($E_k$) are orthogonal to each other and are of unit norm?

Comment: No, I have not checked it.